# How can we do 2 way communication using Akka-remote-access in java

Tags: java, akka, akka-remote-actor

By searching on net, I am able to do 1 way talk but when the receiver typed any thing in its console it give the error as below and also want to know how the distributed akka system works on java,i got some help from [https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-code-samples]  but it was in .net.

please help me in creating a java based distrebute akka system.

```
[ERROR] [12/10/2015 11:04:41.414] [default-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-8] [NettyTransport(akka://default)] failed to bind to /10.208.19.135:8091, shutting down Netty transport
[ERROR] [12/10/2015 11:04:41.443] [Application-Actor-System-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [Remoting] Remoting error: [Startup failed] [
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup failed
at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:136)
at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:201)
at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:108)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:99)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:47)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
at com.wipro.hdfc.dispatch.actors.FilePicker.onReceive(FilePicker.java:12)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /10.208.19.135:8091
at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389)
at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:372)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 ]
 [ERROR] [12/10/2015 11:04:41.506] [Application-Actor-System-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Application-Actor-System/user/FilePicker] Failed to bind to: /10.208.19.135:8091
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /10.208.19.135:8091
at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389)
at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:372)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have pasted indicates you are trying to bind one app to a network port that is already in use, a common mistake learning Akka remoting is to try to run two actor systems on the same computer using the same port which is not possible, each system requires a unique port when running on the same computer.

I'd recommend reading up on the docs and playing around a bit with some sample projects that does work rather than trying to learn by trial and error.

There are multiple sample projects available through activator that covers Akka remoting and clustering in Java, for example: http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-sample-remote-java

You can find docs for the Java side of Akka remoting here:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/java/remoting.html

Comment: Hi Johan, the sample akka project is running fine , but can u please suggest me ,what changes and files i need to put in the another machine when i'll run the same project remotely between two machines.

Comment: You would have to change the `common.conf` to reflect the hostname/ip of the system you are running on which can be accessed by the other system and then the remote actor paths in `remote-creation.conf` and `LookupApplication.java` to point to towards the other system.

Comment: hey Johan , it works for me ,thanks for your responce